# Geometric Sequences Problem

Tags: geometric-series

The formula for geometric sequences is $a = (a1 * r^{n-1})$, right?

Why isn't it working for this problem? $400, 320, 256\cdots$ What is the $6$th term?

$a_6 = 400\times{4/5}^5$?

Comment: It should work. The answer is $\dfrac{16384}{125}$ isn't it?

Comment: I'm getting 64/125?

Comment: how are you getting that?

Comment: I'm putting those numbers into my calculator. I first tried it on my tablet's calculator, then I reached for my scientific one. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you're doing $400\times\dfrac{4}{5^5}$ rather than $400\times\left(\dfrac{4}5\right)^4$.

Comment: I rolled back my edit since it caused misinterpretation of the problem.